# for loop in python with decimal number as step

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.6

I want to make a for loop that looks like this:

```
for x in range(0, 1, 0.1):
    print(x)
```

obviously it throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       for i in range(0, 1, 0.1):
>   TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

So it there a way in python 3.6 to make a for loop with floating point?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `numpy`'s arange instead of range:

```
import numpy as np
for x in np.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Keep in mind you may not get exactly the numbers you expect, because `0.1` can't be represented exactly as a finite binary fraction. I like Simon's approach of using integers and dividing by 10 better; it's less prone to accumulated rounding errors.

Answer (score 7):

Why not divide an integer and convert it into a float value?

```
for x in range(0, 10, 1):
    print(x/10)
```

Here you range from 0 to 10 and the divide the output by 10 to get a floating point.

Comment: yes. I kinda should have thought about this, I guess its past experience from python2.x that made me scared to divide integer